# Unbound constructor with two modules

Tags: ocaml

I have two files : number1 and number2.

number 1 :

```
type 'a t = | Empty | X of 'a
```

number2 :

```
open number1 

type a = int number1.t
    
let test c = match c with 
  | Empty -> ()
  | _     -> ()
```

I get the error: Unbound constructor Empty.

What I don't understand is that c is of type `int number.t`, so that Empty is well defined since I am opening the module number1 in number2. So why I am getting this error?

Comment: Hi hfjei, module names are supposed to start with an Uppercase letter. This should produce a syntax error. What is written in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

As PatJ said. Uppercase the module name.

```
open Number1

let test c f_str =
  match c with
  | Empty -> print_endline "Empty"
  | X x -> Printf.printf f_str x

let () = test (X "G4143") "%s\n"
```